# problem in running complex multiple table mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i need to show pages'details , now i used this query to fetch from 3 tables

group_concat( )

its working fine but shows array of tags and topics duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting extra rows from the join.  Add DISTINCT to the GROUP_CONCAT construct:

```
SELECT  table_stories.*,
  table_stories.sid,table_tags.tid,table_topics.topicid,
  group_concat(DISTINCT table_tags.tag ) as mytags,
  group_concat(DISTINCT table_topics.topicname ) as mytopics
FROM table_stories,table_tags,table_topics
```